# scalajs-jquery jQuery get method?

Tags: scala.js

I'm trying to rewrite some code from JavaScript with "jQuery" to "Scala js" with "scalajs-jquery"

Here is my code:

```
val imgWidth: Int = jQuery(".advertise-wrap img").get(0).asInstanceOf[dom.html.Image].naturalWidth
```

This gives me error in web browser console:

> jQuery$1(...).get(...) is
>   undefined

What I'm doing wrong? How correctly to get first element?

Comment: It looks like you're doing the right thing. Are you sure `jQuery(".advertise-wrap img")` returns a non-empty selection? What if you `println(jQuery(".advertise-wrap img").length)`?

Comment: You are right. Thank you. Just silly mistake. Make your comment answer please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're doing the right thing. Make sure that `jQuery(".advertise-wrap img")` returns a non-empty selection. For example, you can test that with

```
println(jQuery(".advertise-wrap img").length)
```